# Detect color spread amount in OpenCV

Tags: performance, opencv, computer-vision, histogram

I have 2 color objects.One color is less than other color.color amount will be 5%-10%.

Image will be black and white.
If Black amount is less than certain amount,software must be generate an output.
How can I calculate black/white color amount?
How many time will get for this process for 500x800 image?

Comment: if there are only black and white pixels you can use `cv::countNonZero` to get all white pixels and `black pixels = width*height - white pixels`. If you have GRAYSCALE instead of black and white you should give some sample images. You will have to first segment the objects before you can do any counting.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, can you try being more specific?

Comment: I have black and white image.I want to calculate black or white pixel count.then i want to calculate percentage of black/white pixel.I will try @Mick's system.Thanks..